# Android - Styling string with html markup

Tags: android

In my Android app, I'm trying to dynamically change the color of part of a text following the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML). But, this is not working. The color is always the same. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Here's what I have in my `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="red_status">Status: <font color="#FF0000">Red</font></string>
<string name="green_status">Status: <font color="#00FF00">Green</font></string>
```

And, here's my `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/charcoal_grey"
    android:letterSpacing="-0.01"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@{item.status == Status.RED ? @string/red_status : @string/green_status}" />
```

Comment: First, try getting rid of the binding expression and just using one of those two strings. If that works, then perhaps that binding expression uses `getString()` instead of `getText()`, and so it wipes out the formatting. You may need to write a custom binding adapter. If just using the string resource directly fails, then `<font>` may not be a supported HTML tag in a string resource.

Comment: @CommonsWare, you're right. That was it. It looks like all formatting is wiped out, and not only `<font>`. I replaced `<font>` with `<b>` and that didn't work either. Thank you!

Comment: When you get this working, you might want to answer your own question. In particular, since I gave you a couple of possible sources of the problem (string resource not handling `<font>` or the binding expression using `getString()`), I'm not certain which one worked for you. :-)

Comment: I ended up using two separate `TextView`s.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare pointed out in the comments, the issue was that the binging expressing uses `getString()` and therefore wipes out the formatting. I ended up using two separate `TextView`s side by side, one for the static part and one for the dynamic Red/Green part.